# USD Currency Formatting in java?

Tags: java

Below is the Code for the Number Formatter :

```
double value = 12345.678;
// locale preference should be retrieved from user preferences
Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("en", "US", "USD");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(defaultLocale);
String formattedValue = nf.format(value);
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

The Output Value : $12,345.68
But here ,I would like to have my ouput value as : $12,345.68 USD.
I need to get USD(Currency Code) at the End of the Value.

Also i am Calling Webservice inorder to get the Value ,How do I pass the Value to the Required field ,and Format it?

Answer (score 13):

This code do the tricks :

```
    double value = 12345.678;
    java.util.Currency usd = java.util.Currency.getInstance("USD");
    java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.US);
    format.setCurrency(usd);
    System.out.println(format.format(value) + " " + usd.getCurrencyCode());
```

Output :

```
$12,345.68 USD
```

Comment: If the locale isn't dynamic is there much point in the extra method calls?

Comment: I understand your intentions, but clearly he needs no dynamic functionality here. Besides, you've hardcoded the `"USD"` value as well.

Comment: Yeah in the example i have hard coded the USD string in the get instance, but in a real application that value could come from a configuration file for example ... Keep your opinion, but i still think that my approach is more flexible and without any doubt better overall ...

Comment: I actually agree with you. If I wanted dynamic locales then it's an excellent method. I just wanted you to justify it in this situation :)

Comment: A quick Question if i do want to apply a percentage Symbol for Number for example , by input is 0.2 my output value Should be 0.2%.

Comment: You can use NumberFormat anyway, take a look here : http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-numberformat-to-format-a-percent.html . However it is another question, if you want more detail you should open another question with that subject ...

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you just append that value yourself?

```
System.out.println(formattedValue + " USD");
```

Comment: Thanks, and alse How to do i pass the Value from the Webservice ,Is that i hard coded the value right ,would you please provide with exampple.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is a different question. And more detail will be needed.